# How to construct a nested map from tuples (or something similar)?

Tags: java, dictionary, nested, tuples

In Java, 
I need to create a Map that looks like this:

(for clarity, say this is a map of username to location to boolean)

```
Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> someMap = 
     usernameStream.stream().
     .flatMap(username -> locations.stream().map(
          loc -> getSomeBooleanFromInfo(username, loc))
     .// somehow make this into a nested map?
```

I've tried toMap and I know of groupingBy but for some reason I just can't get it to nest given that the way I have it set up above just returns a stream of booleans...

Any recommendations on how I can restructure this so that I can map them properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean getSomeBooleanFromInfo(String username, String loc) {
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> locations = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> someMap = usernames.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Function.identity(),
                    username -> locMap(username, locations))
            );
}

private static Map<String, Boolean> locMap(String username, List<String> locations) {
    return locations.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            loc -> getSomeBooleanFromInfo(username, loc)
    ));
}
```

I suppose, that location is the String as well as username.